# Why is multiple inline IFs faster than a loop with one IF per array entry

Tags: javascript, v8

Angular has the following interesting [function implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/text.ts#L62) which instead of looping through an array of values takes them as parameters and performs `if` checks inline. I assumed it was done for performance purposes so I created [this simple performance test](https://jsperf.com/many-ifs-vs-loop):

```
function checkAndUpdateTextInline(v, def, v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9) {
    let changed = false;
    const bindings = def.bindings;
    const bindLen = bindings.length;

    if (bindLen > 0 && checkAndUpdateBinding(v, def, 0, v0)) changed = true;
    if (bindLen > 1 && checkAndUpdateBinding(v, def, 1, v1)) changed = true;
    if (bindLen > 2 && checkAndUpdateBinding(v, def, 2, v2)) changed = true;
    if (bindLen > 3 && checkAndUpdateBinding(v, def, 3, v3)) changed = true;
    if (bindLen > 4 && checkAndUpdateBinding(v, def, 4, v4)) changed = true;
    if (bindLen > 5 && checkAndUpdateBinding(v, def, 5, v5)) changed = true;
    if (bindLen > 6 && checkAndUpdateBinding(v, def, 6, v6)) changed = true;
    if (bindLen > 7 && checkAndUpdateBinding(v, def, 7, v7)) changed = true;
    if (bindLen > 8 && checkAndUpdateBinding(v, def, 8, v8)) changed = true;
    if (bindLen > 9 && checkAndUpdateBinding(v, def, 9, v9)) changed = true;

    return changed;
}
```

versus dynamic version:

```
function checkAndUpdateTextDynamic(v, def, values) {
    const bindings = def.bindings;
    let changed = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (checkAndUpdateBinding(v, def, i, values[i])) {
            changed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And inline version seems to be 25% faster than dynamic. What could be the reason for that? Is [inline caching](http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/06/03/explaining-js-vms-in-js-inline-caches.html) in play here? How can I debug it using `d8`?

Comment: They both look inefficient--why not immediately return true if a change is found?

Comment: @Will I guess because it not only checks but updates as well? :)

Comment: @Will, because we need to perform `checkAndUpdateBinding` for each binding

Comment: In the first code `bindLen` is always 0 so `checkAndUpdateBinding()` is never called. In the second code it's called 10 times.

Comment: Oh, yeah, its right there in the name :/

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov, can you please take a look at this question? Maybe suggest a way to debug it using `d8`?

Comment: You can't ping users that haven't participated in a question. Anyway, the codes do completely different things so comparing their performance is meaningless.

Comment: @JJJ, well, it does the same thing in the sources of Angular

Comment: The other code calls a function 10 times and the other calls it 0 times. The other is slower because those function calls take time.

Comment: @JJJ, _The other code calls a function 10 times and the other calls it 0 times_ - what function? they both call `checkAndUpdateBinding` function the same number of times

Comment: `const bindings = def.bindings;` In the inlined example, that's an empty array, so your `checkAndUpdateBinding` function is never getting called. You're also testing a lot of setup instead of setting up before the test.

Comment: That's not fully true, I think @JJJ refers to `bindings.length` vs `values.length` in your second case you check the values in the first case the length of the bindings is used

Comment: Like I said earlier, `bindLen` is always 0 so `bindLen > n` is always false when n >= 0. `&&` does short-circuiting, so if you have `false && a()` then `a()` is never called because the interpreter knows that the expression can't be true. That's what's happening in all those if statements in the first code.

Comment: Ultimately, there's no full representation here in the question, so there's no real question to answer.

Comment: @JJJ, I see what you mean now. Thanks for observing it. I've updated my test and the loop variant is still 25% slower

Answer (score 4):

First, the two versions are not equivalent: the number of iterations is bounded by `bindings.length` in the first and by `values.length` in the second. If they differ, you may get a different number of iterations.

Second, there are several operations that the unrolled version avoids:

- Getting `values.length` on every iteration.
- Accessing `values[i]` on every iteration.
- Reading `i` on every iteration.
- Incrementing `i` on every iteration.
- Jumping back to the beginning of the loop for every iteration.

The first two in particular can be expensive, depending on the amount of dynamic optimisations and specialisation the compiler is able to perform. And if `checkAndUpdateBinding` doesn't do much, that might well be a noticeable overhead. You could try to change the original version to use some of these operations as well, and see where that puts it in the comparison.

Third, this is a micro benchmark. Performance in JavaScript involves so many hidden variables and dependencies on static and dynamic context that micro benchmarks are even more pointless to measure than for other languages. In general, I estimate that 90% of what people measure on jsperf is useless or even misleading.

Fourth, note that loop unrolling is a fairly common optimisation performed by compilers. In some cases it can be a significant win, even in languages that are more efficient than JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I don't use `jsperf` myself because  Vyacheslav Egorov doesn't recommend it. It's my first benchmark, just to make sure that angular guys used the unrolled version for the speed optimization purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Without the loop, there's no need to update or compare `i` (it doesn't exist). Some implementations can be slow with `Array.prototype.length`.

The optimizer could be smart with the unwound version too, because its of a fixed number of steps. The optimizer doesn't know whether `values` is 1 item, 10 items, 100 items or 10 million items.

Comment: This operations don't cost much time. It is surprising that it cost 25% of the time.

Comment: There's still a `>` comparison on each line.

Comment: yeah, thanks, that's what is immediately obvious, I was perhaps after some deeper insights